# What could cause these fields to be reverted to unsortable?

Tags: 8, views

I've been working on this view for some time. I've 5 page and 5 block displays and have a table in each. I click the table settings, sort every field that needs to be sorted, then save the view, export it on my dev, import in on prod and suddenly that sortable attribute becomes reverted. How do I debug it and fix it?

Comment: After you save it on dev, have you tested it to confirm that the fields are actually sortable?

Comment: Yes I tested it.

Comment: When you say "suddenly the sortable attribute becomes reverted" - what do you mean? You import on prod and everything works as expected (fields are sortable) for a period of time? How long?

Comment: When I go to the page created, I see that the fields aren't sorted so I go to settings and I see that the boxes I previously checked are not unchecked.

Comment: What is your import/export process?

Comment: `lando drush cex --destination=../config`, provided that I'm in `web`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139400/discussion-between-kartagis-and-sonfd).